# Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'visit' of null

Tags: angular, null, promise, typeerror

Posting this in case someone else gets the same error because the stack trace gives zero indication what caused the issue.

Comment: At least post whatever "unhelpful" stack trace you got. Otherwise this question isn't really helpful at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had the state in the wrong spot within my animation.

I had this:

```
trigger('flyInOut', [    
transition('void => *', [
  state('in', style({transform: 'translateX(0)'})),
  animate(300, keyframes([
    style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateX(-100%)', offset: 0}),
    style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(15px)',  offset: 0.3}),
    style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateX(0)',     offset: 1.0})
  ]))
])
```

Notice `state` should be above `transition` not below it.